# IOs code signing clarification

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, code-signing

As I understand there are 4 possible ways to distribute applications on IOs:

1. Development
2. Ad Hoc
3. Enterprise
4. App Store

I understand how the Development way of distribution works. You need to submit a certificate request to Apple and it issues a certificate for you. Then you use this certificate to sign your applications.

However, it is unclear how Ad Hoc, Entreprise and App Store certificates work.  In particular:

- Ad Hoc can be installed on a wide range of divice, however, you do
  not need to specify the devices in provisioning profiles. Do you need
  to submit a special request to obtain Ad  Hoc certificate, and how
  the enforcement on the level of device works?
- Similarly, as I understand Enterprise certificate can be used to
  install apps on different device (you do not need to specify them in 
  advance). It seems that Enterprise is very similar to App Store
  certificate, i.e., I do not see the difference between them. How the
  security check of certificates works for Enterprise?

My intuition that Apple works as a Certificate Authority but signs all these types of certificates with different root certificates, i.e., developer requests are signed with Developer Apple root certificate, and Enterprise is with Enterprise Apple Root certificate. Then, during the installation on the device the type of the root certificate is checked and the corresponding decision is enforced. Am I right?

Comment: it is all explained here in detail : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer lies in provisioning profiles and not certificates or their authorities.

There's no such thing as an Ad Hoc certificate. There are only Distribution certificates and Development certificates. This is true for Enterprise accounts too, whose certificates are exactly the same (aside from account of provenance type). So Ad Hoc, App Store and Enterprise are all distribution certificates. All your certificates are signed by the same authority: The Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority, and as such they can't  have different root CAs.

The differences lie in the provisioning profiles themselves, which are simply plists signed by Apple. iDevices trust some part of the WWDR certificate chain (the root CA?) and if the signature checks out, the provisioning profile is interpreted and a decision is made on whether a given app can be installed or run.

**Provisioning profiles say who can run what and on which devices.** They're signed by Apple so a device can verify what they say.

The differences between the profile types that I can see are:

Enterprise profiles have

```
<key>ProvisionsAllDevices</key>
<true/>
```

Ad Hocs have

```
<key>ProvisionedDevices</key>
<array>
  UDIDs! You do, in fact, need to specify them for Ad Hoc!
</array>
```

And App Store profiles appear to have no special provisioning information. In fact I'm not sure they ever actually get installed on a device.

The command `security cms -D -i your.mobileprovision` is useful for exploring provisioning profiles.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I need some more clarification. According to your answer and to this article(http://www.raywenderlich.com/2915/ios-code-signing-under-the-hood), before distributing an app you need to create a provisioning profile, which contains the list of UDIDs and sign this profile with your key. Then I do not understand the following thing: it seems that I can create an Enterprise Profile, sign it with my key and distribute apps without publishing them in App Store?

Comment: You don't sign the profile with your key, Apple signs it with its. So you can't just give yourself enterprise distribution, Apple has to do that. To get an enterprise account, you have to agree not to distribute outside your company.

Comment: So this means that the process differs for different types of distribution. For Development and Ad Hoc cases a developer must sign app (because the provisioning profile also contains AppId) provisioning profile by himself, while Entrerprise must be signed by Apple and distributed back to the Enterprise representative. Correct me if I'm wrong. However, then it is unclear the check logic on a IDevice. If the provisioning profile is signed directly with Apple then allow to install apps on all devices, if with developer certificate - then only on specified UDIDs?

Comment: The certificate changes nothing because ALL provisioning profiles are signed by Apple. All APPs that are not from the appstore are signed by you. The provisioning profiles say who can run what and on which devices. Dev and Ad Hoc profiles allow install on specified devices via UDID and Enterprise on any device.

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience! Now I think, I understand everything. Within a process of creating app project you also in Provisioning Profile Manager creates a provisioning profile which is distributed with the app. This profile in any case is signed with Apple, thus, there is no difference in the process for Enterprise and Developer distribution ways.

Answer (score 3):

A Venn diagram I created to simplify the understanding of iOS provisioning profiles.
[image: A Venn diagram I created to simplify the understanding of iOS provisioning profiles.]
See the Google Drawing doc here: https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1Td19Lf94Lep3h7jFD2mYdO564Y_LiWBaFaartDE8riU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, this diagram does not clarify how this protection is enforced on a device level. I think that @RhythmicFistman answer share more light on this question. However, I really appreciate your answer.

Comment: No problem! I created the diagram to make sense of how the profile puzzle fits together in terms of 1) the two different iOS developer programs and 2) which profiles from each program require UDIDs and which do not. It should be noted that an Enterprise subscription DOES NOT allow you to deploy to the App Store. You would need subscriptions for BOTH types of developer programs in order to build apps for both the App Store deployment AND internal "in-house" deployment.